# What's the best way to implement a number that has an optional minimum or maximum value?

Tags: python

I want to create a number that you can set a maximum and/or minimum value to. So it'd work like this:

```
>>> n = myNum(5, minimum=0, maximum=10)
>>> n += 10
>>> print(n)
10
>>> n = myNum(-12, minimum=3)
>>> print(n)
3
```

The problem is that however I try to implement it seems to become very tedius and long despite the fact that it seems like such a simple concept. Is there an elegant way to do this without, say, overriding every single magic method having to do with numbers?

Comment: Hint: `max(low, min( high, var))`

Comment: Not in the way you are trying to do it.

Comment: How are you trying to do it?

Comment: and are you then proceeding to define its very own algebra?

Comment: @BrenBarn the best I could do was inherit from int, then manually override every single __iwhatever__ with something like max(low, min(high, var)) as NightShadeQueen and coincoin suggested, then add the methods set_min and set_max. But that seems rather silly and repetitive.

Comment: aren't ints immutable to start with?

Comment: @user3471004: Compared to what?  It's not surprising that you would have to override lots of methods from `int`, since the behavior you're describing is quite different from that of `int`.

Comment: ints are indeed immutable

Comment: @BrenBarn It's not that I'm surprised so much as I don't know of a better way. The  concept of what I want is not difficult to grasp, but I thought more experienced programmers might have a more elegent solution that's only a few lines long.

Comment: I think you'd have to make your own class, but the only method you'd have to overwrite would be `__setattr__`, I'd think. `float("inf")` and `float("-inf")` might make your life easier.

Comment: `__setattr__` might do the trick. I've never used it before, but it might be a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather do something like that

```
n = min(max(5,10),0)
```

and

```
n = min(-12,3)
```

From your comment, you can make a convenient function :

```
def between_min_max(value, min_val, max_val):
  return min(max(value, max_val), min_val)
```

and use it later in your code :

```
min_val = 0
max_val = 10
n = between_min_max(5,min_val,max_val)
# and you can reuse min_val, max_val later
```

Comment: The only issue is that whenever I want to change these values, I'd have to think about what the limits are for anything that could change them. Say I were writing a simulation and an agent had some characteristic, speed. If every time that agent encountered something that modified their speed, like an incline, or better shoes or something then I'd have to consider how speed works every time I write something that can modify it. I want to just make speed have a max and min and then not think about it ever again.

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill. You could try creating your own class and then overloading operators on your class. You can create the class `mynum`:

```
class mynum:
  def __init__ (self, val, minval, maxval):
    self.val = val
    self.minval = minval
    self.maxval = maxval
```

and declare your numbers in your code as instances of `mynum`:

```
n = mynum(5, 0, 10)  # for instance
```

Then you can overload operators on your class, so that it behaves the way that you want it to. For adding, put this inside of your `mynum` class definition:

```
def __add__(self, operand):  # overload things like n + 10
  self.val += operand
  if self.val > self.maxval:  # replace checks with max(min(...)...) if you like
    self.val = self.maxval
  elif self.val < self.minval:
    self.val = self.minval
  return self.val
```

[This post](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/operator-overloading-python) has some good info on a starting point for this. The down side is that this method would require that you overload every operator that could possibly give you an invalid value for your `mynum` instance.